# owl carousel и статический блок

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Пытаюсь сверстать вот такой макет : http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/58112.html
Тут в первом блоке есть слайдер, для него я решил использовать owl carousel тк там используется touch. Но вот проблема там есть центральный блок и он статический, а прокручивается только background. Я блоку задал position:absolut, поставил его в центр. И получается теперь что при свайпе по статическому блоку background не прокручивается, тк находиться над слайдером (логично), но на этом сайте как-то сделано так что этот центральный блок вообще никак не влияет на прокрутку. Как этого добиться? Я просмотрел код сайта, но ничего не нашел нужного.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте css-свойство `pointer-events: none;` для блока - тогда любые нажатия будут проходить "сквозь" него на блок ниже.

А если у вас в блоке есть кликабельные элементы - ссылки, кнопки, поля ввода - для них задайте `pointer-events: initial;`.

Comment: супер!!! спасибо!!!